# Service worker failing after email link/redirect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app

I created a website using React Create App (v1), and I'm hosting with Firebase hosting. My site looks great when visiting normally (ie - just typing in the url and browsing); however when I send emails ("Reminder to sign in", etc.) and I have an email button that links back to my site I get an error. Note: it looks like the email button has a redirect tracker on it (I assume so SendGrid or someone can see email stats).

My service worker is failing to load:
[image]

And console shows this error:

```
 The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT
```

How can I fix this? Why does service worker failed to load when my site is accessed through email?